# Undefined when trying to access object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm creating a javascript program that prompt users to input coordinates (x,y) of 2 points of each line to do further functions.

```
    const numOfLines = parseInt(prompt("Please enter number of lines: "));

    //point object
    function Point(x, y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    let firstPoints = new Array(numOfLines);
    let secondPoints = new Array(numOfLines);

    for(let i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++)
    {
        let firstPointMessage = "Please enter the first point's coordinates x, y of line " + (i+1);

        // substring input to add (x,y) to an array
        let firstPoint = prompt(firstPointMessage).split(",");

         //add point(x,y) to firstPoints array
        let fp = new Point(parseInt(firstPoint[0]) ,parseInt(firstPoint[1]));
        firstPoints.push(fp);

        let secondPointMessage = "Please enter the second point's coordinates x, y of line " + (i+1);
        let secondPoint = prompt(secondPointMessage).split(",");
        let sp = new Point(parseInt(secondPoint[0]) ,parseInt(secondPoint[1]));
        secondPoints.push(sp);
    }

    while(num < numOfLines)
    {
        document.write(firstPoints[num].x);
        ....further action
        num++;
    }
</script>
```

Error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')** occurred for line **document.write(firstPoints[num].x);**

And **firstPoints[num]** actually has values when I tried to debug, but I just can't get the value out of it to use for further action. What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: `new Array(numOfLines);` creates an array with empty elements. `firstPoints.push(fp);` pushes new elements after the empty elements. Either use `new Array` and overwrite the empty elements or use `firstPoints.push(fp); without `new Array`.

Comment: thank @jabaa. I've been working on this for hours and couldn't figure out why. You saved me on this one.